# Get all directions using Bing Map SDK in UWP

Tags: bing-maps, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

Is it possible to get all driving directions with a specified FROM and TO location in UWP using Bing Map SDK? (just like windows 10 map app)

Answer (score 1):

Yes:
Get a driving or walking route and directions by calling the methods of the MapRouteFinder class - for example, GetDrivingRouteAsync or GetWalkingRouteAsync. The MapRouteFinderResult object contains a MapRoute object that you access through its Route property.

When you request a route, you can specify the following things:
•You can provide a start point and end point only, or you can provide a series of waypoints to compute the route.
•You can specify optimizations - for example, minimize the distance.
•You can specify restrictions - for example, avoid highways.

You can use sample code like this one:

```
    private async void GetRouteAndDirections()
    {
        // Start at Microsoft in Redmond, Washington.
        BasicGeoposition startLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
        startLocation.Latitude = 47.643;
        startLocation.Longitude = -122.131;
        Geopoint startPoint = new Geopoint(startLocation);

        // End at the city of Seattle, Washington.
        BasicGeoposition endLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
        endLocation.Latitude = 47.604;
        endLocation.Longitude = -122.329;
        Geopoint endPoint = new Geopoint(endLocation);

        // Get the route between the points.
        MapRouteFinderResult routeResult =
            await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(
            startPoint,
            endPoint,
            MapRouteOptimization.Time,
            MapRouteRestrictions.None);

        if (routeResult.Status == MapRouteFinderStatus.Success)
        {
            // Display summary info about the route.
            tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new Run()
            {
                Text = "Total estimated time (minutes) = "
                    + routeResult.Route.EstimatedDuration.TotalMinutes.ToString()
            });
            tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new Run()
            {
                Text = "Total length (kilometers) = "
                    + (routeResult.Route.LengthInMeters / 1000).ToString()
            });
            tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

            // Display the directions.
            tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new Run()
            {
                Text = "DIRECTIONS"
            });
            tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

            foreach (MapRouteLeg leg in routeResult.Route.Legs)
            {
                foreach (MapRouteManeuver maneuver in leg.Maneuvers)
                {
                    tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new Run()
                    {
                        Text = maneuver.InstructionText
                    });
                    tbOutputText.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tbOutputText.Text =
                "A problem occurred: " + routeResult.Status.ToString();
        }

    }
```

More info here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631250.aspx#getting_a_route_and_directions

Comment: Can you please mark as anwser to close the thread ? Many thanks :)